# How do I get notified of monitor re-activate? I don't get a WM_SYSCOMMAND message when monitor is turned on again

Tags: winapi, vb6

I need to track the monitor getting to sleep and awaking from sleep (energy saving):

```
Private Const SC_MONITORPOWER = &HF170&
Private Const MONITOR_OFF = 2&
Private Const MONITOR_ON = -1&
Private Const MONITOR_STANDBY = 1&
```

---

Here is my subclassing code:

```
If (uMsg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) Then
    If (wParam = SC_MONITORPOWER) Then
        If (lParam = MONITOR_OFF) Then
            'I do receive this event!
            Debug.Print("Monitor is turned off")
        ElseIf (lParam = MONITOR_ON) Then
            Stop 'This is never called
        Else
            Stop 'This is never called
        End If
    End If
End If
```

If the monitor goes to sleep, a WM_SYSCOMMAND message is broadcast.

However, I don't get a WM_SYSCOMMAND when the monitor is turned on again (for example by moving the mouse).

How do I track then monitor gets re-activated / turned on again?

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand):

> In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low-order bits of the wParam parameter are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct result when testing the value of wParam, an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator.

You are not doing that, so it is possible that you are not detecting `SC_MONITORPOWER` properly when the monitor is turned on, if other system flags are also present in the `wParam`.

Try this instead:

```vb
If (uMsg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) Then
    If ((wParam And &HFFF0) = SC_MONITORPOWER) Then
        If (lParam = MONITOR_OFF) Then
            Debug.Print("Monitor is turned off")
        ElseIf (lParam = MONITOR_ON) Then
            Debug.Print("Monitor is turned on")
        Else
            Debug.Print("Monitor is on standby")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

**UPDATE**: however this is moot, as you say you are not even getting a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message when the monitor is turned on. In that case, try [registering for Power Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/registering-for-power-events), requesting to receive change notifications for either `GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON` or `GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE` (Win8+):

> GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE
>
> 6FE69556-704A-47A0-8F24-C28D936FDA47
>
> The current monitor's display state has changed.
>
> Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008: This notification is available starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
>
> The Data member is a DWORD with one of the following values.
>
> 0x0 - The display is off.
>
> 0x1 - The display is on.
>
> 0x2 - The display is dimmed.

> GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON
>
> 02731015-4510-4526-99E6-E5A17EBD1AEA
>
> The primary system monitor has been powered on or off. This notification is useful for components that actively render content to the display device, such as media visualization. These applications should register for this notification and stop rendering graphics content when the monitor is off to reduce system power consumption. The Data member is a DWORD that indicates the current monitor state.
>
> 0x0 - The monitor is off.
>
> 0x1 - The monitor is on.
>
> Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012: New applications should use GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE instead of this notification.

Your window will then receive a [`WM_POWERBROADCAST(PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) message whenever the requested monitor state changes.

Comment: Thank you, but with your approach, I don't get the SC_MONITOR event anymore. The wParam is 61808. And there is only 1 WM_SYSCOMMAND message received: When the monitor goes off. So my question is unfortunately not answered yet. I will add my findings to the question.

Comment: 61808 (0xF170) is `SC_MONITORPOWER`. `(61808 And &HFFF0) = 61808`, so `If ((wParam And &HFFF0) = SC_MONITORPOWER) Then` should evaluate as True when `wParam = 61808`. In any case, this is moot, since you just now said that you are not even getting a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message when the monitor is turned on. You did not say that yesterday.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it evaluates as true. And it is as you said: I don't even get a WM_SYSCOMMAND when the monitor is turned on. That is my problem. I thought that my code "        ElseIf (lParam = MONITOR_ON) Then
            Stop 'This is never called
        Else
            Stop 'This is never called
        End If" made that clear. I see now that it wasn't really clear.